# Creating a Android Icon Pack

Tags: android, icons, pack

I've just finished creating a bunch of icons in Adobe Illustrator for my Android phone. My problem is now, how can I make an icon pack like those you can download from the Play Store? You might think that there must a lot tutorials for this purpose, but I don't seem to find them useful, and it confuses me more than it benefits.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know anything about the subject. I simply wanna make my icons, created in Illustrator, available on my Android phone.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instrument (Icon generators allow you to quickly and easily generate icons from existing source images, clipart, or text.): https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: Do I put the files into a new project in Android Studio afterwards?

Comment: @JensKvist you can put files in your existing project too.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, whichever icon you go with you will need different resolutions of it such as ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, etc.. and that can be done in two ways,

1. Manually by making each image the correct size
2. Using a asset generator like Android Asset Studio  https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

In terms of creating the actual icon, you dont need any specific "Android Icon Tutorial". You can use any generic logo or icon tutorial and just create it in the correct size. Read this link for icon sizes:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html
Then you can simply watch and "logo" or "icon" tutorial and follow along. Then I would use Android Asset Studio to create all DPI's
And this one for other icons:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html